# Can I use asp.net mvc to deploy a reverse proxy server with appharbor.com's free plan

Tags: reverse-proxy, appharbor

In China, some websites are blocked. These include Google, Twitter etc..
But we can access [appharbor.com](http://appharbor.com/) in China.

So I want to deploy a reverse proxy service on AppHarbor, so that I can access Twitter from this reverse proxy service.

Is this workable? If so, how can I do it? And why am I interested in using AppHarbor? Because I'm a .net(C#) developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should definitely be possible to build something like this. There is even some code already out there:

- http://code.google.com/p/reverseproxy/
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/reverseproxy.aspx

As much as I admire your dedication to making blocked sites available to people in China (and I really do admire it), using AppHarbor might not be the best tool for the job. If the AppHarbor application is identified as a reverse proxy, it might cause all AppHarbor hosted sites to be blocked. This will negatively impact developers that use AppHarbor to host applications with users in China. The [AppHarbor Program Policies](https://appharbor.com/page/programpolicy) prohibit (amongst other things) actions that "Promote or encourage illegal activity" or "Interfere with other users' enjoyment of the Service", so you might want to consider whether you'd be in compliance with those terms.

(disclaimer, I'm co-founder of AppHarbor)